# Ubuntu installation not showing correct HDD size

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am a complete newbie to Linux family ( been with Windows till now). I am trying to install Ubuntu from my USB drive so that my laptop has both windows 7 and Ubuntu along side. When I am selecting the automatic installation option, incorrect HDD size is coming. For eg my HDD is of 320Gb with close to 80 GB free but on the ubuntu installer it is showing something else. I am worried that by installing I don't lose any data. Here're screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you resize the 320 GB partition and create a new ext4 partition before installing ubuntu?

Comment: No I did not do anything of that sort. Just booted up from USB onto ubuntu and started the install.

Comment: you have to do that.Shutdown your pc,boot from ubuntu live usb click on try ubuntu option on startup.Now open gparted application,take a screenshot then upload it to imgur.com.Finally paste the link here.

Comment: I wish I could.. but dont have enough reputation to upload screen shot :(

Comment: post only the uploaded image link,i post the image on your question.

Comment: Images installed at

http://imgur.com/g4mSCFT

http://imgur.com/6blflZq

Comment: follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and resize your sdb3 partition.

Comment: Resizing not allowing size change.

http://imgur.com/3UTCoAS

Comment: you have to remove the red mark,so that you can resize that partition.For this boot into windows and make a restart not shutdown.After restarted shutdown the pc.Then boot from live disk and the resizing operation.

Comment: If I select automatic option for installing Ubuntu on top of window, shouldn't the partitioning be automatically taken care of ?

Comment: Not clear on why the sdb3 used size is coming as unknown

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and classic confusion of base 10 vs base 2.  For decades the computer industry defined the term "Kilobyte" to mean 1024 bytes rather than 1000.  Hard drive manufacturers like to inflate their numbers to sell more units, so they define it to be 1000, thus when they say a 320 GB drive, they mean a drive with 320,000,000,000 bytes.  In base 2 units, that is only 298 GiB.  Note the addition of the 'i' as in recent years the trend is to use this to indicate it really is base 2 rather than base 10, as one might expect with "GB".

Comment: Not confused about base 10 and base 2 but about the partitioning concepts over here

Comment: @hpant, what?  Your question was why the size isn't what you expect.  The reason is your expectation is wrong because of the difference between base 10 and base 2.

Comment: Noo my question is that why is the 320GB HDD not being available for installing Linux

Comment: @hpant, that isn't what the question says...

Comment: sorry about the confusion. My question was more around why I am not able to install Linux by making a partition in the 320GB HDD. Basically its about why is the used portion of the 320 gigs drive coming as space and NOT some value .

Comment: @hpant, you should edit your question then to clarify it.  You simply said the installer showed "something else".  What exactly did it say?  Do you mean that it says your NTFS partition has no free space?  I noticed that there is a red ! in the gparted image indicating something is wrong with the partition.  Check the details to find out what, and you probably need to run `chkdsk /f` from windows to fix it.